# What is a more efficient way to process numpy arrays based on multiple criteria?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy, convolution

I have written some code that for a range of years (eg. 15 years), `ndimage.filters.convolve`is used to convolve an array (eg. array1), then where the resulting array (eg. array2) is above a randomly generated number, another array (eg. array3) is given a value of 1. Once array3 has been assigned a value of one it counts up for every year, and when it eventually reaches a certain value (eg. 5), array1 is updated in this location.

Sorry if this is a little confusing. I've actually got the script working by using `numpy.where(boolean expression, value, value)`, but where I needed multiple expressions (eg. `where array2 == 1 and array3 == 0`), I used a for loop to iterate through each value in the arrays. This works great in the example here, but when I substitute the arrays for larger arrays (The full script imports GIS grids and converts them into arrays), this for loop takes a few minutes to process for every year. As we have to run the model over 60 years 1000 times, I need to find a much more efficient way to process these arrays.

I've tried to use multiple expressions within numpy.where but couldn't work out how to get it to work. I also tried zip(array) to zip the arrays together, but I couldn't update them, I think because this created tuples of the array elements.

I've attached a copy of the script, as mentioned earlier it works exactly as I need it to. However, it needs to do this more efficiently. If anyone has any suggestions that would be great. This is my first post regarding python so I still consider myself a novice.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import random
from pylab import *

###################### FUNCTIONS ###########################

def convolveArray1(array1, kern1):

    newArray = ndimage.filters.convolve(array1, kern1, mode='constant')

    return newArray


######################## MAIN ##############################

## Set the number of years
nYears = range(1,16)

## Cretae array1
array1 = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=np.int) # vegThreshMask

# Add some values to array1
array1[[4,4],[4,5]] = 8
array1[5,4] = 8
array1[5,5] = 8

## Create kerna; array
kernal = np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.float32)

## Create an empty array to be used as counter
array3 = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=np.int)

## iterate through nYears
for y, yea in enumerate(nYears):

    # Create a random number for the year
    randNum = randint(7, 40)
    print 'The random number for year %i is %i' % (yea, randNum)
    print

    # Call the convolveArray function
    convArray = convolveArray1(array1, kernal)

    # Update array2 where it is greater than the random number    
    array2 = np.where(convArray > randNum, 1, 0)
    print 'Where convArray > randNum in year %i' % (yea)
    print array2
    print 

    # Iterate through array2 
    for a, ar in enumerate(array2):
        for b, arr in enumerate(ar):
            if all(arr == 1 and array3[a][b] == 0):
                array3[a][b] = 1
            else:
                if array3[a][b] > 0:
                    array3[a][b] = array3[a][b] + 1
            if array3[a][b] == 5:
                array1[a][b] = 8

    # Remove the initial array (array1) from the updated array3   
    array3 = np.where(array1 > 0, 0, array3)
    print 'New array3 after %i years' % (yea)
    print '(Excluding initial array)'
    print array3
    print    

print 'The final output of the initial array'
print array1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you could gain a substantial speedup if you start using broadcasting. For example, starting from your line `# Iterate through array2` we can remove the explicit loop and simply broadcast over the variables we want to change. Note I'm using `AX` instead of `arrayX` for clarity:

```
# Iterate through A2

idx  = (A2==1) & (A3==0)
idx2 = (~idx)  & (A3>0)
A3[idx ]  = 1
A3[idx2] += 1
A1[A3==5] = 8
```

In addition, this greatly improves code clarity once you get used to this style as you aren't explicitly dealing with the indices (your `a` and `b` here).

### Is it worth the trouble?

I asked the OP to do a speed test after trying the code above:

> If you do implement loop change, please let me know the speed-up on your real-world code. 
>   It would be useful to know if the advice given is simply glorified syntactic sugar, or has a notable effect.

After testing, the response was a substantial 40x speedup! When dealing with large arrays of contiguous data where simple masks are being performed, `numpy` is a far better alternative over native python lists.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I did a couple of test runs comparing the speed of this compared to my original and this took 18 seconds as opposed to over 12 minutes! So it definitely has a notable effect. Thank you (it does also look a lot better)

Comment: @TravisMoon that's great! I really appreciate you posting the results, I'll direct people here when they ask if `numpy` is worth the trouble for basic array manipulations. I expected a speedup, but nothing on the order of 40x!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you were trying to use multiple conditions in `np.where` using expressions like `array1 > 0 and array2 < 0`.  This doesn't work because of the way boolean operations work in Python, as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#and).  First, `array1 > 0` is evaluated, then it is converted to a boolean value using the `__nonzero__` method (renamed to `__bool__` in Python 3).  There isn't a unique useful way of converting an array into a bool, and there is currently no way of overriding the behaviour of the boolean operators (though I believe this is being discussed for future versions), so in numpy, `ndarray.__nonzero__` is defined to raise an exception.  Instead, you can use `np.logical_and`, `np.logical_or`, and `np.logical_not`, which have the behaviour you would expect.

I don't know how much of a speedup this will give you, though.  If you do end up performing lots of array indexing operations in loops, it might be worth looking into [cython](http://cython.org/), with which you can easily speed up array operations up by moving them into a C extension.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up how python handles boolean expressions, someone else at my work also mentioned np.logical_and for use with numpy arrays. For this job I used the answer given above, but if I get a chance at some stage I'll try this as well to see which is faster. I'm not sure if the computer I'm using at work has cpython, but I might still look into it. Thank you.